# Total Weight in Cart Summary. Change symbol

Tags: magento2, totals, checkout-page

Using this tutorial https://www.siphor.com/add-a-custom-total-in-magento-2/ I created a totals for total weight of products. Generally it almost works but the prefix with currency symbol is automaticaly added to my total. I would like to change it to "lbs". How can I do that?[image]

Answer (score 0):

getValue() in js file formats the amount to two decimal places and also adds the current currency symbol. It was necessary to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

In the file `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/custom_amount.js`, change the line `return this.getFormattedPrice(price);` to `return price+' lbs';`. The complete codes is below:

```
// app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/custom_amount.js

define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
                template: '[Vendor]_[Module]/checkout/summary/custom_amount'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,

            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode() && this.getPureValue() !== 0;
            },

            getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('custom_amount').value;
                }
                return price+' lbs';
            },
            getPureValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('custom_amount').value;
                }
                return price;
            }
        });
    }
);
```